# Webdriver initialization error java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService$Builder.loadSystemProperties()V

Tags: windows, macos, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, geckodriver

I'm facing this error, on windows and mac both, while launching the browser.

```
java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService$Builder.loadSystemProperties()V
```

We updated selenium version in march, and it has been working fine till last week.

I'm able to set the absolute path with `System.setProperty` and verify it with `System.getProperty` afterwards.

I have seen few similar posts like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70565409/selenium-chrome-driver-error-java-lang-abstractmethoderror-receiver-class-org-o), but they are about the binary paths.

Can someone help explaining this error or point in right direction please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error is usually caused by a version mismatch between the version of the WebDriver and the version of the browser you are using. Just make sure that everything is updated and compatible, like the versions and all. If you're absolutely sure everything is up to date then you can try using a different version of the WebDriver or a different browser

Comment: After wasting hours on browser and binaries, the issue got resolved once we upgraded from 4.8.3 to 4.9.1.