# java.lang.IllegalStateException using ChromeDriver with Selenium Java

Tags: java, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, illegalstateexception

Code trials:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class SeIntro {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:\\Users\\ramak\\Downloads\\chromedriver_win32.zip.exe" );
        WebDriver driver=new ChromeDriver(); 
    }
}
```

Snapshot:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

`chromedriver_win32.zip` is a [zip](/questions/tagged/zip) type file a format for compressed file archives, allowing packaging of multiple files and directories into a single file.

Where as [`System.setProperty()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60061951/7429447) line expects the absolute path of the [ChromeDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59927747/7429447) binary executable.

---

### Solution

You need to unzip the `chromedriver_win32.zip` and pass the absolute path of the [ChromeDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53744026/7429447) binary executable as follows:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:\\Users\\ramak\\Downloads\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe" );
```