# Selinum driver showing error "Could not start a new session. Possible causes are invalid address of the remote server or browser start-up failure."

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

```
package newproject;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;

public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String[] args)throws InterruptedException{
    
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:\\selenium-java-4.8.0\\selenium-chrome-driver-4.8.0.jar");
    
    ChromeDriver driver=new ChromeDriver();
    driver.get("https://tequicky.com/page-login.php");
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    
    driver.findElement(By.name("fullname")).sendKeys("test");
    driver.findElement(By.name("email")).sendKeys("test@gmail.com");
    driver.findElement(By.id("Subscribe")).click();
    
    
}
}
```

The error is

```
SLF4J: No SLF4J providers were found.
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See https://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#noProviders for further details.
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Could not start a new session. Possible causes are invalid address of the remote server or browser start-up failure. 
Host info: host: 'LAPTOP-8Dbbb5LD', ip: '192.168.2.103'
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:561)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:229)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:157)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chromium.ChromiumDriver.<init>(ChromiumDriver.java:101)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:82)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:50)
    at newproject.MyClass.main(MyClass.java:11)
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Timed out waiting for driver process to start.
Build info: version: '4.8.0', revision: '267030adea'
System info: os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '14.0.2'
Driver info: driver.version: ChromeDriver
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.start(DriverService.java:218)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:98)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:543)
    ... 6 more
```

This is my first selenium project , please help

See https://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#noProviders for further details.
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Could not start a new session. Possible causes are invalid address of the remote server or browser start-up failure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove/delete the below line, you don't need it:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:\\selenium-java-4.8.0\\selenium-chrome-driver-4.8.0.jar");
```

With selenium version 4.6.0 and later, you do not really need to set property.

By the way, the issue in your code is that your `System.setProperty` is pointing to a `JAR` file, where as you should provide the location of `exe` file. For chrome, file should say `chromedriver.exe`

Answer (score 2):

If at all you are using the [`System.setProperty()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60061951/7429447) line you need to download the [ChromeDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59927747/7429447) version matching to the [google-chrome](/questions/tagged/google-chrome) version installed in your system from [ChromeDriver - WebDriver for Chrome](https://sites.google.com/chromium.org/driver/downloads?authuser=0) page, unzip the [ChromeDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53744026/7429447) executable and pass the absolute location through the *`webdriver.chrome.driver`* property as follows:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:\\path\\to\\chromedriver.exe");
```