Unable to initialise chrome browser in selenium
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Users\\Dev\\webdrivers\\chromedriver.exe");

driver = new Chromedriver():
driver.manage().window().maximize();

exception:
org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Could not start a new session. Possible causes are invalid address of the remote server or browser start-up failure.


Can you share a snippet of the code that you're trying to execute?

What version of selenium are you using? If it's v4.6.0 or higher then you can use SeleniumManager to handle the chromedriver.exe Check this answer - https://stackoverflow.com/a/75508001/7598774

Few more references to know about Selenium Manager - https://stackoverflow.com/a/77574327/7598774 , https://stackoverflow.com/a/76463081/7598774

var driverFolder = @"C:\Users\Dev\webdrivers\chromedriver.exe";
driver = new ChromeDriver(driverFolder);
