# org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException:Couldnotstart anew session.Possible causes are invalidaddressoftheremoteserverorbrowserstart-upfailure

Tags: selenium-webdriver, automation, webdriver

## Versions used

Firefox version: 114.0.1 (64bit)
selenium-java jars version: 4.10.0
gecko driver 0.33.0
java 17

## program:

```
package webdriverexamples;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class Add {
public static void main(String args[]) {
    System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","F:\\geckodriver.exe");
    WebDriver driver=new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.navigate().to("https://www.google.com/");
    driver.close();
}
}
```

> 

## Error:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Could not start a new      session. Possible causes are invalid address of the remote server or browser start-up failure. 
Host info: host: 'LAPTOP-XXXXXXXX', ip: 'XXX.XXX.X.X'
   at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:549)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:227)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:154)
   at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>`your text`(FirefoxDriver.java:151)
   at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:146)
at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:130)
at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:125)
at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:110)
at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:100)
at webdriverexamples.Add.main(Add.java:8)
```

Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Timed out waiting for driver process to start.
Build info: version: '4.10.0', revision: 'c14d967899'
System info: os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '17.0.7'
Driver info: driver.version: FirefoxDriver
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.start(DriverService.java:215)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:119)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:531)
... 9 more`

I want to open firefox browser and navigate to url  ,but getting error.
Please help me on this....

Answer (score 0):

This error message...

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Could not start a new      session. Possible causes are invalid address of the remote server or browser start-up failure.
```

...implies that the [GeckoDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45331403/7429447) was unable to initiate/spawn a new *Browsing Context* i.e. [firefox](/questions/tagged/firefox) session.

Using [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54482491/7429447) ***v4.10.0***, [GeckoDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45331403/7429447) ***v0.33.0*** and [firefox](/questions/tagged/firefox) ***v114.0.1*** you don't require to pass the absolute path of [GeckoDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45510453/7429447) through [`System.setProperty()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60061951/7429447) line any more.

---

### Solution

Your effective minimal code block would be:

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.get("https://www.google.com/");
```

Console Output:

```
Jun 11, 2023 3:58:24 AM org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService$Builder getLogOutput
INFO: Driver logs no longer sent to console by default; https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/drivers/service/#setting-log-output
```