# org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException - Could not start a new session. Response code 500

Tags: java, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to setup a simple program in selenium and run into

```
org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Could not start a new session. Response code 500. Message: unknown error: cannot find Chrome binary.
```

Please find below sample code and also the error details

```
@Test
    public void shouldAnswerWithTrue()
    {
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver = new ChromeDriver();

        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();
        driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(40, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.get("https://www.google.com/");

        driver.findElement(By.name("q")).sendKeys("YouTube");
        WebElement searchIcon = driver.findElement(By.name("btnK"));
        searchIcon.click();
        assertTrue( true );
    }
```

After running the above program, I notice the error below:

```
Aug 02, 2023 9:56:56 PM org.openqa.selenium.manager.SeleniumManager lambda$runCommand$1
WARNING: The chromedriver version (96.0.4664.45) detected in PATH at /usr/local/bin/chromedriver might not be compatible with the detected chrome version (115.0.5790.114); currently, chromedriver 115.0.5790.102 is recommended for chrome 115.*, so it is advised to delete the driver in PATH and retry
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.

org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Could not start a new session. Response code 500. Message: session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 96
Current browser version is 115.0.5790.114 with binary path /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome
```

Comment: Try commenting out the `System.setProperty` line. Since you are using selenium `v4.11.0`, setting the driver path is optional now. See if it works after removing `System.setProperty`. Check this answer if it helps - https://stackoverflow.com/a/76463081/7598774

Comment: Thanks @Shawn - I tried running the code after removing set property statement but I still get an error as now it seems the webdrivermanager is stuck at version 96 for chrome.

Comment: Can you edit your question and share your latest code and latest error trace please?

Comment: Thanks @Shawn - I have revised the question. It seems this may be specific to mac, but please let me know in case you need further info. Cheers

Comment: Strange, selenium should have downloaded the latest 115 version `chromedriver.exe` and should have used it. Instead it is still trying to use 96 version driver. Does your laptop have access to internet? Hope no firewalls are blocking? Try deleting the old driver from this path `/usr/local/bin/chromedriver`, and see if that helps selenium to download and use latest chromedriver.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Shawn for your help and responding to my question. I removed the chromedriver from /usr/local/bin/chromedriver and it seem to have worked. Could you please answer my question so that I can mark it as the answer as it would help then help others as well? Many thanks, Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are on Selenium v4.11.1, you don't need to set the `chromedriver.exe` path manually using `System.setProperty`, nor do you need any third-party tool such as `WebDriverManager`. Selenium has built-in tool known as `SeleniumManager` will do the driver management automatically.

**Regarding your updated ERROR:** There isn't any issue in your code; Selenium should download and use latest `chromedriver.exe` matching the version of your Chrome browser which is v115. Somehow, it is still using the v96 driver.

**Solution:** Just delete the old driver (v96) from the cache. I.e., from this path (*usr/local/bin/chromedriver*). And then let Selenium download the latest driver programmatically. This should solve the issue.

Comment: Hi @Shawn, I am using Selenium 4.12.0 and as suggested by you in this answer it is running perfectly fine at my local machine. But when I run same scripts at Jenkins server placed at Azure using Kubernetes-docker infra, I am getting error org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException in Jenkins Console logs. The browser and driver downloaded are of same version while running at Jenkins. Looking forward to your response. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This error message...

```
Aug 02, 2023 9:56:56 PM org.openqa.selenium.manager.SeleniumManager lambda$runCommand$1
WARNING: The chromedriver version (96.0.4664.45) detected in PATH at /usr/local/bin/chromedriver might not be compatible with the detected chrome version (115.0.5790.114); currently, chromedriver 115.0.5790.102 is recommended for chrome 115.*, so it is advised to delete the driver in PATH and retry
...
...
org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Could not start a new session. Response code 500. Message: session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 96
Current browser version is 115.0.5790.114 with binary path /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome
```

...implies that the path you have passed through the [`System.setProperty()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60061951/7429447) line contains [ChromeDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59927747/7429447) ***v96.0.4664.45*** which is *old* and *ancient* whereas [google-chrome](/questions/tagged/google-chrome) is of ***v115.0***.

---

### Using Selenium Manager

As you are using [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54482491/7429447) ***v4.11.0*** you can remove the line of code:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","//Users//user//year//TestSelenium//src//test//java//org//example//chromedriver");
```

Additionally, you need to delete the [ChromeDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53744026/7429447) ***v96.0.4664.45*** from *`/usr/local/bin/`*, so [Selenium Manager](https://www.selenium.dev/blog/2022/introducing-selenium-manager/) which is now integrated with *Selenium* can download the matching [ChromeDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59927747/7429447) silently in the background and execute the test.

Your effective code block will be:

```
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
driver.manage().window().maximize();
driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();
driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(40, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
driver.get("https://www.google.com/");
```

Comment: Thanks undetected selenium - I removed the set property statement and now I see following error : org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Could not start a new session. Response code 500. Message: session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 96
Current browser version is 115.0.5790.114 with binary path /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome

Answer (score 1):

A new warning message was just added so that people are notified to delete conflicting driver versions in their path: https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/fbfa5d26ce96ca067d62b6921915e640498e3b09/rust/src/lib.rs#L496

After determining your versions, it will print a message like this: `The chromedriver version (114.0.5735.90) detected in PATH at /usr/local/bin/chromedriver might not be compatible with the detected chrome version (115.0.5790.114); currently, chromedriver 115.0.5790.170 is recommended for chrome 115.*, so it is advised to delete the driver in PATH and retry` (Assuming you're not masking warnings)

Once these conflicting versions are deleted, Selenium Manager will automatically download drivers to `~/.cache/selenium` by default when calling `WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();` in Java.